# Keycloak how to use JWT for admin rest api

Tags: java, keycloak

in keycloak 3.4.2 I am successful on using clientid&clientsecret to connect to server (by using keycloak java api):

```
    KeycloakBuilder keycloakBuilder = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
             .serverUrl(AUTH_SERVER)
             .realm(ADMIN_REALM)
             .grantType("client_credentials")
             .clientId("admin-cli")
             .clientSecret("XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")
             .grantType("client_credentials")                
             .resteasyClient(client);
```

now I am trying to use JWT (Json Web Token) but I havent found any example on internet.

I changed client authenticator to "signed jwt" and put a JWKS URL:

[image: credentials tab]

Now how can I change my java code in order to use this new kind of authentication ?

Comment: Are you providing a proper JWKS in `http://myhost/myapp/k_jsks`?

Comment: No. Could you please be more detailed how to do it ? in java code how we should use it ? Thanks